# Django 1.7 add data from view, NOT admin

Tags: python, django

How would I go about using a form (or anything) to add a new entry into my database from a view (using a POST request from HTML) instead of using the admin page. I am already aware how to alter an entry (via the polls tutorial at [the django website](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial03/)), now I need to know how to create a new entry in the database

I can't find any answers for this for Django 1.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well that's an easy question. Just read this section of the documentation entitled [Working with forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/).

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can create your `form` from your `model`. take a look at [ModelFrom](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/).

Comment: would I create a forms.py and put the example from the link in there?

Comment: yes, you cant put all forms in `forms.py` and import it in `views.py`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the docs well! You basically need a save() method.This is what you do in the views:

```
def view(request):
    '''Take the data from HTML form'''
    name  = request.Post.get("name") 


    '''Then get a model instance'''
    mod = Model()
    mod.name = name #assign the desired values to the model field
    mod.save() # Save the data into database table
```

Its not the best of examples and I haven't used ModelForms, which are way better.But you seem to have problem understanding the basics of saving the values in database.So this might help!